# ¿Cómo tomar el valor más alto en una vista (view) en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo este codigo :

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ProductView
as 
Select p.ProductID, p.ProductName, COUNT(p.ProductID) as 'NUMERO DE VECES VENDIDO'
from Products p
inner join [Order Details] o 
ON p.ProductID = o.ProductID GROUP BY p.ProductName, p.ProductID
```

Que me permite saber cuantas veces **se ha comprado un producto**, solo necesito que me **muestre** el **mas vendido**, el mas alto de la lista que me sale pero no lo logro, me complica que no puedo usar order by en una view.
Si pueden ayudarme seria lo mejor!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo entendido que dentro de un view no es posible usar un order by salvo con un top pero al usar top no puedo estructurar bien el order by con el inner join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una subconsulta con la consulta original que devuelva el top 1 de  `COUNT(p.ProductID)` ordenado de forma `desc` y usar ese valor como filtro con un `having`.

```
Select p.ProductID, p.ProductName, COUNT(p.ProductID) as 'NUMERO DE VECES VENDIDO'
from Products p
inner join [Order Details] o 
ON p.ProductID = o.ProductID 
GROUP BY p.ProductName, p.ProductID
HAVING
COUNT(p.ProductID) = (


SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(p.ProductID)
from Products p
inner join [Order Details] o 
ON p.ProductID = o.ProductID 
GROUP BY p.ProductName, p.ProductID
ORDER BY COUNT(p.ProductID) DESC


)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por compartirme lo que sabes!, me ayudaste muchísimo, efectivamente tu código es el correcto, gracias por la breve explicación. Las clases en linea se me dificultan un poco!
Estaba con mucha duda pues habia leido que no se puede usar "ORDER BY" en una VIEW salvo que uses top, offset, pero tu lo usas y funciona... tocaria estudiar mas. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el operador Apply

```
create table products (productid int, productname varchar(10))
create table [order details](id int, productid int)
go
insert into products 
values
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c');
insert into [order details]
values
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,2);
go
Create view dbo.ProductView 
As
    Select p.ProductID, p.ProductName, NUM.VECES as 'NUMERO DE VECES VENDIDO'
        from Products p
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS VECES
            FROM [order details] O
            WHERE O.productid = p.productid
            ) AS NUM
```

La gracia del operador está en que recibe como "parámetro", el productId de la tabla externa. Aunque realmente el motor no lo ejecuta de ese modo.

Y con la misma técnica, puedes crear una función y el código te quedaría todavía más simple.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_CountProductOD (@ProductId int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'NUMERO DE VECES VENDIDO'
            FROM [order details] O
            WHERE O.productid = @ProductId

)
GO

Create view dbo.ProductView_2 
As
    Select p.ProductID, p.ProductName, fn.[NUMERO DE VECES VENDIDO]
        from Products p
        CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_CountProductOD (P.ProductID) AS fn
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

la solucion es simple con un **with** te permite implementar subconsulta condiciones de una consulta

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ProductView
as 
with Totales As
(
    Select p.ProductID,p.ProductName,COUNT(p.ProductID) as MaxVendido
    from Products p
    inner join [Order Details] o 
    ON p.ProductID = o.ProductID 
    GROUP BY p.ProductName, p.ProductID
)
select top(1) p.ProductID,p.ProductName,MaxVendido 
from Totales 
order by MaxVendido desc
```

espero que te sirva